# How to safely fix this type mismatch on abstract method with generics and Supplier lambda

Tags: java, generics

We have a cache framework which we use to wire application-specific cache types (such as this authentication cache shown below) to various implementations (e.g. ehcache, redis, memcached etc). The framework is just an abstraction layer to allow the application to define and manipulate its cache similar to a map of key-value pairs, while specifying its app-specific key class and value class.

So for example we have:

```
public class AuthenticationCache extends BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<AuthenticationCacheKey, AuthenticationCacheEntry> {...}

public class AuthenticationCacheKey implements IAuthenticationCacheKey {...}

public class AuthenticationCacheEntry implements IAuthenticationCacheEntry {...}
```

and elsewhere in the application, the app overrides an abstract method which provides a *Supplier* for its cache:

```
@Override
protected <K extends IAuthenticationCacheKey, E extends IAuthenticationCacheEntry> Supplier<BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<K, E>> getAuthCacheSupplier() {
    Supplier<BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<K, E>> supplier = () -> {
        return new AuthenticationCache();
    };
}
```

But this creates a compiler error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from AuthenticationCache to
>   BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl

Generics are kicking my backside these days. Am I doing this completely wrong? Can I safely cast the supplier to `(BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<K,E>)` since I know after type erasure it'll be the same runtime and I know that the concrete key/value classes of `AuthenticationCache` satisfy K,E (e.g. extends IAuthenticationCacheKey/IAuthenticationCacheEntry) ?

Comment: I assume you can't modify any of those classes, not even `AuthenticationCache `, nor the one providing the `Supplier`. Is this right?

Comment: can you change the signature of `getAuthCacheSupplier`?

Comment: I can change anything - this caching framework is our own API. As said the goal of it is to be able to support multiple applications (6 or so) with a variety of caching (the "high level" caches, about a dozen different types of caches, some use simple Strings as keys, others more complex) wired to external cache providers (ehcache, redis etc). The details & configuration of the cache providers is entirely hidden from the high level caches

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat the compiler by using something like this:

```
protected <K extends IAuthenticationCacheKey, E extends IAuthenticationCacheEntry> Supplier<BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<K, E>> getAuthCacheSupplier() {
    return () -> new AuthenticationCache().toBaseAuthenticationCacheImpl();
}


class AuthenticationCache extends BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<AuthenticationCacheKey, AuthenticationCacheEntry> {

    public BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl toBaseAuthenticationCacheImpl(){
        return this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cast is technically safe, as long as you can guarantee that `K` and `E` are always `AuthenticationCacheKey` and `AuthenticationCacheEntry`, but the compiler can't give you that guarantee.

Assuming these classes:

```
class BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<K extends IAuthenticationCacheKey, E extends IAuthenticationCacheEntry> {}

interface IAuthenticationCacheKey {}

interface IAuthenticationCacheEntry {}
```

A safe solution is to change the return type to:

```
@Override
protected Supplier<BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl<?, ?>> getAuthCacheSupplier() {
    return AuthenticationCache::new;
}
```

As long as the `BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl` is just used to produce something that implements `IAuthenticationCacheKey` and something that implements `IAuthenticationCacheEntry`, but is not a consumer.

Depending one how you actually use the type parameters of `BaseAuthenticationCacheImpl` you might even be able to just drop them completely and exchange them for `IAuthenticationCacheKey` and `IAuthenticationCacheEntry` directly. (Sometimes the best solution to a generics problem is to not use generics)